# Can I use the transfer function of a servo DC motor as a close approximation to the transfer function of a stepper motor?

Tags: stepper-motor, model

I have been trying (just spent many hours on this) to find/calculate/derive the transfer function of a hybrid stepper motor. I don't need an exact transfer function (the electrical and mechanical equations are very complex! at least, in my opinion). I just need a good estimate or simpler equation that i can use to model the motor in Matlab/Simulink.

Here are the equations for a hybrid stepper motor: https://se.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/ref/steppermotor.html

During my search for some answers, I came across the dynamical equations for a servo DC motor and I managed to figure out the transfer function calculations.

Can I use a servo DC motor transfer function for a pretty close modelling/simulation of a stepper motor?